# nHibernate Validator custom IMessageInterpolator

Tags: c#, nhibernate, validation

Has anyone managed to get a custom IMessageInterpolator working to
enable customisation of error messages. I have tried following the
instructions on this web page but to no avail.
http://codelog.climens.net/2009/03/04/nhibernate-validator-custom-messages/

Looking into the code the DefaultMessageInterpolator seems pretty
baked into the framework so is there anything I am missing.

I have included my unit tests to show how I am implementing it.

```
namespace TestValidator
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestValidator()
        {
            var customer = new Customer();

            ClassValidator classValidator = new ClassValidator(customer.GetType());
            InvalidValue[] validationMessages = classValidator.GetInvalidValues(customer);

            Assert.IsTrue(validationMessages.Length == 1);
            Assert.IsTrue(validationMessages[0].Message == "may not be null or empty");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestCustomInterpolator()
        {
            ValidatorEngine ve = new ValidatorEngine();
            NHVConfiguration nhvc = new NHVConfiguration();
            nhvc.Properties[Environment.MessageInterpolatorClass] = typeof(CustomMessageInterpolator).AssemblyQualifiedName;
            ve.Configure(nhvc);

            var customer = new Customer();

            ClassValidator classValidator = new ClassValidator(customer.GetType());
            InvalidValue[] validationMessages = classValidator.GetInvalidValues(customer);

            Assert.IsTrue(validationMessages.Length == 1);
            // THIS TEST FAILS!!
            Assert.IsTrue(validationMessages[0].Message == "CustomMessageInterpolator");
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public virtual int CustomerId { get; set; }

        [NotNullNotEmpty]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomMessageInterpolator : IMessageInterpolator
    {
        public CustomMessageInterpolator()
        {

        }

        public string Interpolate(string message, IValidator validator, IMessageInterpolator defaultInterpolator)
        {
            return "CustomMessageInterpolator";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your NHibernate and NHibernate.Validator configs too?

Comment: This is the complete configs. There is no more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got this to work finally. Before calling the validator in my repository I explicitly create and pass the Interpolator as a parameter.

```
ClassValidator classValidator = new ClassValidator(obj.GetType(), null, new CustomMessageInterpolator(), 
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, ValidatorMode.UseAttribute);
InvalidValue[] validationMessages = classValidator.GetInvalidValues(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked over your problem and the most interesting is that:

```
Assert.AreEqual(typeof(CustomMessageInterpolator), ve.Interpolator.GetType());
```

is true. I assume the problem is in the fact that CFG was already configured with DefaultMessageInterpolator, and the

```
ve.Configure(nhvc);
```

does not have the effect, because ClassValidator uses nomatter of this configuration the DefaultMessageInterpolator. This is the cause why for Climens, it worked in App.config, not in nhvalidator.cfg.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I am using fluent Nhibernate to register the NHibernate validator and the Message interpolator is integrated correctly.  The key to remember is that the Shared Engine Provider provides Singleton access to the Validator Engine.  If you try to instantiate a new validator Engine in your application, it will not have the message interpolator configured as the only way to configure it is during initialization as demonstrated below.

```
        Environment.SharedEngineProvider = new NHibernateSharedEngineProvider();

        var fluentConfiguration = new FluentConfiguration();

        fluentConfiguration
            .SetMessageInterpolator<CustomMessageInterpolator>()
            .SetDefaultValidatorMode(ValidatorMode.OverrideAttributeWithExternal)
            .IntegrateWithNHibernate
            .ApplyingDDLConstraints()
            .And
            .RegisteringListeners();

        var validatorEngine = Environment.SharedEngineProvider.GetEngine();
        validatorEngine.Configure(fluentConfiguration);
        configuration.Initialize(validatorEngine);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you require a validator to check an entity at runtime, instead of creating a new instance of the validator, you can request a validator from the engine you registered when configuring NHV.

```
var engine = NHibernate.Validator.Cfg.Environment.SharedEngineProvider.GetEngine();
return engine.GetClassValidator(YourEntityType);
```