# NHibernate Validator - passing resource manager and key

Tags: c#, .net, validation, nhibernate-validator

According to the NHibernate Validator documentation here:

http://nhforge.org/wikis/validator/nhibernate-validator-1-0-0-documentation.aspx

I should be able to pass my resource manager so I can use that for validation error messages. See:

> Alternatively you can provide a ResourceManager while checking programmatically the validation rules...

And:

> If NHibernate Validator cannot resolve a key from your ResourceManager nor from ValidatorMessage, it falls back to the default built-in values.

It even shows and example of doing just this in an attribute on a entity property:

```
 // a not null numeric string of 5 characters maximum
    // if the string is longer, the message will
    // be searched in the resource bundle at key 'long'
    [Length(Max = 5, Message = "{long}")]
    [Pattern(Regex = "[0-9]+")]
    [NotNull]
    public string Zip
    {

        get { return zip; }
        set { zip = value; }
    }
```

**However, as far as I can see it doesn't specify how you pass the resource manager to the validation framework - does anyone know how to do this?**

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404309/nhibernate-validator-how-to-validate-custom-properties

Comment: @Jon, Thanks, I read your suggestion on the that question - It's interesting interesting,  and I'll give it some consideration. I'd still like to know how to do this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this post](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/create-a-custom-message-interpolator-for-nhibernate-validator.aspx) and answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905081/nhibernate-validator-custom-imessageinterpolator) (it describes some gotchas in using message interpolator).

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks this is useful.  However, the NHV documentation suggests that it is easier than having to write your own custom message interpolator : "Alternatively you can provide a ResourceManager while checking programmatically the validation rules...", maybe the docs are misleading?

Comment: `DefaultMessageInterpolator` has method `Initialize` that accepts culture and couple of ResourceManagers - normal and fall-back. You can cast your `ValidatorEngine.Interpolator` to `DefaultMessageInterpolator` and re-initialize it.